# Is it possible to create mutable versions of objects read in from a plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, plist, immutability

I'm reading into my application a plist which at the top level is an array.  It's simple enough to make sure the array starts as mutable

```
self.plistData = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDataSource" ofType:@"plist"]] mutableCopy];
```

Within each element of the array is another array, each of those contains a dictionary.

Based on a tablecell selection I'm changing attributes for the dictionary at the selected index:

```
[self.cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow] setValue:@"YES" forKey: @"isSelected"];
```

I'm getting the error `'-[__NSCFDictionary removeObjectForKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'` when I attempt to change a dictionary value.  The error makes sense if the NSDictionary read in by the plist is immutable.

Is there any way to read in content from a plist and make sure any arrays or dictionaries are read in as mutable versions?

Comment: Code provided is incomplete. Where are you using - removeObjectForKey?

Comment: can you show code of how you are iterating through the dictionary/array ?

Comment: There is no build in "mutableCopy" that transform each sub level object into mutable versions. `mutableCopy` only do it at top level where it's called.

Comment: @SamB I've added the line of code the is triggering the crash/error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use `NSPropertyListSerialization` and passing the proper options to get mutable containers.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDataSource" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:nil error:nil];
self.plistData = array;
```

Ideally you will make use of the `error` parameter and do proper error checking but this will get you started.

This code will load the plist and return a mutable array and every contained array and dictionary will also be mutable.