# Saving Bool Value on to Plist and Update

Tags: swift, save, plist

if my root is a array and is filled with dictionaries so on viewcontroller 1 is set up

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Animals", ofType: "plist")
let dics = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!) as! [NSMutableDictionary]
```

and viewcontroller 2 is set up

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Animals", ofType: "plist")

if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path!){
let dics = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!) as! [NSMutableDictionary] 
dics.setValue(isFavorite, ForKey: "fav")
dics.write(toFile: path!, atomically: true)
```

I put isFavorite as a varible at the top of the code and if user hits the button isFavorite changes from false to true and vice versa. isFavorite = !isfavorite. Now if I run this code it states that NSMutableDictionary has no member setValue or write. I am not sure how to let the system know that I clicked on the second dictionary cell from the list of dictionaries in the array from the plist in ViewController 1 and I want to change that key value that has "fav" to true from false from ViewController 2. I know it sounds a bit confusing so let me rephrase it. ViewController 1 has bunch of animals Dogs, Cats, Fish etc. So now if user clicks on Cats it takes them to viewcontroller 2 and on viewcontroller 2 I want a favorite button if user clicks on it it updates the Plist file and the boolean value in cats changes to true from false. I tried using userDefaults method and if I change the boolean value for one animal it changes for all animals. So I made another key value of Boolean in all animals in the plist. I want that Boolean Value to change when user hits the Favorite Button on ViewController 2 but it wont save to the plist file.

Updated: So looking at my code I think the problems lies within ViewController 1. On ViewController 1 I wrote:

```
  let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Animals", ofType: "plist")
  let dics = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!) as! [NSMutableDictionary]

  self.orginalData = dics.map{Animals(Type: $0["Type"] as! String, Desc: $0["Desc"] as! String, fav: $0["fav"] as! Bool)}

  self.filteredData = self.original Data
```

then I show it on the tableview on ViewController 1 like this:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  if isFiltering() {
  searchFooter.setIsFilteringToShow(filteredItemCount: filteredData.count, 
  of: originalData.count)
  return filteredData.count
  }

   searchFooter.setNotFiltering()
   return originalData.count
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
     var animals : Animals
     if isFiltering() {
         animals = filteredData[indexPath.row]
     } else {
         animals = originalData[indexPath.row]
     }

   cell.textLabel?.text = Animals.Type
  cell.detailTextLabel!.text = Animals.Desc
  return cell
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `setValue`: You need to call it on a dictionary, not an array.

Regarding `write`: You need to cast to `NSArray`, since it doesn't exist for `Swift.Array`.
It will need to be more closer to something like this:

```
let isFavorite = true // based on user selection
let selectedIndex = 0 // this is the index of the animal selected in VC 1

if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"Animals", ofType: "plist"),
    FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path),
    let dics = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [NSMutableDictionary] {
    let selectedAnimal = dics[selectedIndex]
    selectedAnimal["fav"] = isFavorite // this replaces `setValue`
    (dics as NSArray).write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
}
```

Comment: Okay so when I ran this code and press that favorite Button on viewcontroller 2 I get this error message - Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary  setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'. I thought I put NSMutableDictionary not sure why this error message is popping

Comment: I updated my code above where I think is causing the error message. But I am not sure how to change my code to become a MutableDictionary

Comment: It's because you're loading the plist with immutable containers. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919415/is-it-possible-to-create-mutable-versions-of-objects-read-in-from-a-plist

Comment: Is there a updated version of that because I think swift 4 doesnt accept those syntax anymore. I tried googling NSpropertylistserialization mutable didnt see any recent version of it